# How does the Facebook PHP SDK v5 getAccessToken() function work

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a project I'm working on where I want to use the Facebook PHP SDK v5 to post data to a Facebook page but I'm having trouble making an ajax call to my Facebook script.

this is my `facebook.php` file:

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 echo facebook();

 function facebook(){
    include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Facebook/autoload.php";
    $permissions = ['manage_pages', 'publish_pages'];
    $callback = "https://www.my-domain.com/my-callback-url.php?fb=redirect";

    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
      'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
      ]);

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

    try {
        if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
            $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
        } else {
            $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
        }
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        $res['error'] = 'Error: Graph returned a session error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        return json_encode($res);
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        $res['error'] = 'Error: Facebook SDK returned a session error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        return json_encode($res);
    }

    if (!isset($accessToken)) {
        $redirectUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($callback, $permissions);
        $res['login'] =  $redirectUrl;
        return json_encode($res);
    }else{
        // rest on the script to post to a page
    }
}
?>
```

This is `my-callback-url.php` as well as the page that makes the ajax call to the `facebook.php` file

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['fb'])){
    $code = $_GET['code'];
}else{
    $code = '';
}

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var code = "<?php echo $code; ?>";

if(code !== ''){
    postToFB(code);
}

$('#postButton').on('click',function(){
    postToFB(code);
}

function postToFB(code){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'facebook.php',
        data: {"somePostData": "someValue", "redirectCode":code},
        success: function (data) {
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
            if(json.hasOwnProperty('login')){
                window.location.replace(json.login);
            }
        }
    });
}

});
</script>

?>
```

According to the documentstion on Facebooks website this is how Facebook says `getAccessToken()` works

> Attempts to obtain an access token from an authorization code. This method will make a request to the Graph API and return a response. If there was an error in that process a FacebookSDKException will be thrown. A FacebookSDKException will also be thrown if the CSRF validation fails.

The problem I'm running into is when my user is on `my-callback-url.php` and clicks the `#postButton` the script makes an ajax call to `facebook.php`

If `facebook.php` can't obtain an access token it calls:

```
 $redirect = $helper->getLoginUrl($callback, $permissions);
```

This send the `$redirect` value back to the ajax function in `my-callback-url.php` and the success method sends the user to that redirect url.

Once the user authenticates, Facebook sends the user back to `my-callback-url.php` the full URL callback looks something like this:

```
 https://www.my-domain.com/my-callback-url.php&fb=redirect?code=xxxxxxxxxx?state=xxxxxxxxxx
```

after the callback is made, `my-callback-url.php` runs the ajax script again along with the code parameter obtained from the callback.  My question is how can I pass the code parameter obtained from the callback to the `getAccessToken()` function inside `facebook.php`?

It does not seem that `getAccessToken()` accepts a code parameter.  I'm wondering if I need to set the code parameter into a specific session variable in order for `getAccessToken()` to read it.  Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: _“after the callback is made, my-callback-url.php runs the ajax script again along with the code parameter obtained from the callback”_ - and what is that supposed to be good for …? You should process the code parameter directly where you receive it - and that is in your `my-callback-url.php` script. Get the token there, directly - and don’t involve any AJAX nonsense at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to do anything with the code parameter from the login-redirect URL.

The `getAccessToken()` method gets the code itself, using the class's `getCode()` method which extracts the code from the URL query string. So, once you are back on `my-callback-url.php`, you can call the method and it should return the access token.

This can be seen from method itself in the SDK:

```
/**
 * Takes a valid code from a login redirect, and returns an AccessToken entity.
 *
 * @param string|null $redirectUrl The redirect URL.
 *
 * @return AccessToken|null
 *
 * @throws FacebookSDKException
 */
public function getAccessToken($redirectUrl = null)
{
    if (!$code = $this->getCode()) {
        return null;
    }

    $this->validateCsrf();
    $this->resetCsrf();

    $redirectUrl = $redirectUrl ?: $this->urlDetectionHandler->getCurrentUrl();
    // At minimum we need to remove the state param
    $redirectUrl = FacebookUrlManipulator::removeParamsFromUrl($redirectUrl, ['state']);

    return $this->oAuth2Client->getAccessTokenFromCode($code, $redirectUrl);
}
```

Just one word of warning: do not make multiple calls to `getAccessToken()`—make one call and store the result in a variable. Any subsequent calls using the same code would be seen as a cross-site request forgery and an Exception would be thrown.